# acf display image on user profile

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I am really new at php , so sorry for this very basic question;
i am using ACF to add a metabox to the user profile. So every user has a pic. 
The field is called 'badge', this is defined as an image object (but I don't know if that is correct, I just want the pic to appear on the page)

Then, I try to display the result on each profile page.
On the documentation of acf: 
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

so I tried this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $badge['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $badge['alt']; ?>" />
```

But I am getting lost here. I don't know how to retrieve the correct information and display it.

Could someone please help?

Many thanks, and sorry again for this very basic question i guess!

Sonia

Comment: Do you have that line in your code: `$badge = get_field('badge');` (before the line you've mentioned)?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since the  question has been asked, but here's a working code exemple of what you can do to retreive the Badge custom field on the current logged user:

```
<?php
    $user = "user_".$user_ID;
    $badge = get_field('avatar', $user);
?>
<img src="<?php echo $badge['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $badge['alt']; ?>" />
```

Hope it will help for the future!